# Ternary representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ be two distinct positive integers which only have $1$'s and $0$'s in their ternary representation. I am convinced that $\frac{a + b}{ 2}$ should have at least one $2$ in its ternary representation but I cannot prove it. Also assume that $ a + b $ is even.

Comment: $a$ and $b$ should be distinct, presumably. Do they need to have the same parity so that $\frac{a+b}{2}$ is an integer, or is it okay if $\frac{a+b}{2}$ isn't an integer?

Comment: Yes , they are distinct. I have only considered the case when their sum is even.

Answer (score 3):

If $(a+b)/2$ has only $1$'s and $0$'s in its ternary expansion, then $a+b$ has only $2$'s and $0$'s.  But if $a$ and $b$ have only $1$'s and $0$'s and are not the same, look at the rightmost digit at which they differ. (Actually, you can look at *any* digit at which they differ.)  One of these will be a $0$ and the other a $1$, hence $a+b$ will have a $1$ in that position, in contradiction to the assumption.  Hence $(a+b)/2$ must have at least one $2$ in its ternary expansion.